# Are observations random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, sampling

I'm looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem and more specifically, at [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBccv.png). When it says 'Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ denote a random sample of $n$ independent observations', is it assumed that the $X_i$ are random variables? If so, I don't quite understand it because a random variable is a function from a set of possible outcomes to $\mathbb R$. But for example, if we're interested in measuring weights, $X_i$ is the weight of $i$th sample, which is a number and not a function. So the question is how can $X_i$ be regarded as a function? What is its domain (i.e., what is the set of outcomes in this case), and how is it defined?

Comment: The domain of random variables is usually invisible. It does not matter to probability calculations how exactly the domain is defined, so we do not worry about it. I think of $\Omega$ as an abstract blob (equipped with a sigma algebra and probability measure); each $X_i$ is a function from a blob to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Plus: The CLT is so *central* simply because it does not matter on which probability "blob" those $X_i$ are functions. All that matters is that they are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: Setting aside the domain of $X_i$s, why are they even considered to be functions? As I mentioned in the question, in the example with weights, they are just fixed numbers -- the weights of the corresponding sample items.

Comment: Only when you sample an outcome from your domain do you get the actual measurement. If I sample $\omega \in \Omega$, then my measurements are $X_i(\omega)$. The $X_i$ are functions because they are telling us all the values the random variable can take for a given outcome $\omega$.

Comment: Think of the $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots $ as random variables before you see them and the observed numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ after you see them.  Hence the distinction between saying $\frac13(X_1+X_2+ X_3)$ is an estimat**or** of the expectation and $\frac13(x_1+ x_2+ x_3)$  is an estimat**e** of the expectation